# Can an AI simulate someone that is diagnosed as "Special Needs"?

Tags: ai-design

Do you think it would be possible to train an AI in such a way as to mimic/simulate someone that is diagnosed as "Special Needs"?

Why? Most diagnosis and treatments for people today are subjective, sure it's what a group of like-minded professionals has agreed upon as a valid hypothesis, but, at the same time, there is an absence of the absolute. Could we train an AI to become a "special needs" be a starting point in helping find better ways to unlock the potential and understanding of these differences?

Comment: Creating an AI to accurately simulate any human behaviour to the level at which we could learn from the AI would, currently, be a huge leap beyond our current capabilities.

Comment: To back up Lio's point, training an AI to behave like any kind of life form in order to simulate even a subset of interactions with it, is currently a tall order. You can forget any mammals for a few years yet, let alone humans.

Comment: This leads to another question: Why train an AI to be "special needs"? Now you have a "special needs" robot, and you're back where you started: How do you decipher what differentiates them?

Comment: I don't think this is a good question for this site. It could be a good starter question for a PhD, but I wouldn't expect the question itself to be answered in the eventual thesis.